# specifying events as files to live on Core project instead of service project

Tags: c#, .net, microservices

In my solution I have 3 projects

```
MyProject.Core
MyProject.Services.DataImporter
Myproject.Services.Cars
```

Both `DataImporter` and `Cars` projects are referencing `MyProject.Core` project.
I have an event (`DataImportFinishedEvent`) which is emmited by `DataImporter` service.
`Services.Cars` is subscribed to this event and potentially more services later.
With my current approach, I have this event (`DataImportFinishedEvent`) as a file created
on both services.

Since both services are referencing Core project should I move this event to the Core project? Doing so will have file on one location only.
Is this a good microservice practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general have common projects or libraries is not a good practice in microservices because this way you are coupling the develop and deploy of both services, so when you make a change in the common project, you have to change and deploy the two other microservices.

In the case of the event, the best way is to have different events in both of the services. This not necessarily means that they have to be duplicated. In the producer side you must have an event with all the information needed by any of the potential consumers and in the consumer side you must have an event with the information needed by that service, that can be less.

This way, you decouple the two services and if tomorrow the consumer service need other information provided by the producer you only have to change the consumer side and vice-versa

One way to think about it is when you are consuming a third party api that you are not controlling, you build your own response object with the data provided by the api that you need and this object is different that the one used by the api.